# Repeatedly creating and destroying views in Backbone.js or Marionette.js without creating a "memory leak"

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I suspect that the way I am handling views in backbone.js is flawed in such a way that it is creating a "memory leak".

There is a view that is constantly being overwritten with another copy of itself. The new copy is linked to a different model.

I am creating and adding the view to it's parent view by setting the `el` option when creating the child view.

The strange thing that is happening is that even though a new view is being rendered over top of the old view, when I click the "button" an alert pops up for every childView that was every rendered, even though the button they were listening to should be gone, they respond to the new button.

I've implemented a quick fix by calling a function on the old view to stop listening to events before the new view is added. But **that this problem exists at all tells me that all of the old views are hanging around** and will slow the application over time if the user does not refresh the page often enough.

```
var parent = new (Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
     ui:{
          child_container: '#child-container'
     },
     onRender: function(){
          // Listen to outside event
          ...
     }
     on_Outside_Event: function(new_model){
          // Quick fix prevents multiple alerts popping up for every child view when "button" is pressed
          this.child_view.destroy_view(); 

          // New child view is created and rendered on top of the one that was there before
          this.child_view = childView({
               el:    this.ui.child_container,  // <-- Is this the problem?
               model: new_model
          })
          this.child_view.render();
     }
}))();

var childView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
     events:{
          'click button': 'on_click_button'
     },
     on_click_button: function(){

          // Alert pops up once for every view that was ever displayed.
          alert('Button clicked');  
     },
     // QUICK FIX
     destroy_view: function(){
          this.undelegateEvents();
     }

})
```

In case this is helpful, here is a screen shot of the actual application. A calendar of appointments is on the right. The problem child view - a view of the individual appointment that the user wants to see is on the left.

When I click the "Cancel appointment" button, that function gets called for every appointment that was every displayed in that area, even though I am listening to the event using: `events:{ 'click #cancel-button': 'on_button_click'}`

None of the other buttons, interactions, and other controls have this same issue, I assume because all the others actually live views that are children of the child appointment view and not in the child appointment view itself

[image]

**A possible fix?**

Did a little searching around, does this fix look adequate?

Normally, I think the `removeData().unbind();` and `remove()` functions are called directly on `this.$el`, but this did not work here, I think because I added the child view using the `el` option when it was created (`el:    this.ui.child_container`)

```
var childView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
     ...
     // REAL FIX
     destroy_view: function(){
          this.undelegateEvents();

          this.$el.children().removeData().unbind();
          this.$el.children().remove();
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should make your parent view a LayoutView (that's just an ItemView with added functionality to handle regions iirc), have a region defined for where you want this child view to appear, and then do:

```
  Parent = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend
    regions:
      child: "#child-container"

    on_Outside_Event: ->
      childView = new ChildView(...)
      @getRegion("child").show(childView)
```

(sorry I used coffeescript, it's faster to write, but you can translate easily).

Marionette will handle everything: closing your old child view, unbinding events, etc.

Comment: When I first started using Marionette, I used Layouts a few times, but I don't think I understood them very well. This application is large, there are many levels of parent views and child views. Are there times when it is ok to nest Layouts? If I understand correctly, it is not usually ok to re-render a layout (I almost never re-render views anyway)? When would you use an ItemView and not a Layout? Thanks!

Comment: Layouts are super useful, and the fact that they are nestable is one of the things that makes them great. The marionette doc mentions that they are nestable at will. But you're right, you should avoid re-rendering a big "tree" of nested layouts. But there are a lot of ways to avoid that usually, just by binding your child views to their model, or to whatever is changing, and making them re-render themselves. In your example for instance, why don't you just update the child view model with the data from the new model, forcing it to re-render? Instead of replacing it with a new one?

Comment: I don't update the child view model with new information because there is only one copy of each model. One model is sometimes behind several views. In this example, the appointment detail view on the left side and the view of the appointment in the calendar on the right side use the same model. So for example when changing the "start_time" of the appointment in the detail view, the position of the appointment in the calendar will actually change as the user types. In the future I'd like to add push updates of models from the server.  When that happens, all the views would update as well.

Comment: Just as an aside, I don't think the one-model-many-views architecture is the only way to have multiple views update from a single model. I could create a system of events to update all copies of a model in a one-view-one-model architecture. The way it is now is just the way that seemed to make these most sense when I was designing the application. It would be non-trivial to switch to a one-model-one-view architecture at this point in the development though. I love the design of pathofmaps by the way.

Comment: I see, it definitely makes sense to not update the model if it's meant to represent a different appointment for instance. Then the layout approach is the right one, you just want the parent view to be a layout, and replace the current child view in the appropriate region.